# Expression of Geometric Series Finite Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm currently studying geometric series but I have encountered these problems and by trying to apply what I've learned so far I quite can't figure out **how this would be expressed in sigma notation?** 
$$0.4+(0.4)(0.2)+0.4(0.2)^2+0.4(0.2)^3+0.4(0.2)^4+0.4(0.2)^5$$
I've tried many ways to express this with no success.

**Thanks!**

Comment: '-1' Doesn't mention the effort, source and any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $0.4$ is a common factor to all the terms. Take it out (factorize) to get:

$$(0.4)(1 + 0.2 + 0.2^2 + 0.2^3 + 0.2^4 + 0.2^5)$$

But you know that $1 = 0.2^0$ and $0.2 = 0.2^1$. So it becomes:

$$(0.4)(0.2^0 + 0.2^1 + 0.2^2 + 0.2^3 + 0.2^4 + 0.2^5)$$

We notice that the powers increment by exactly $1$ each time, starting from $0$ and ending with $5$. So we utilize the sigma notation:

$$0.4\sum_{i = 0}^50.2^i$$

---

If you did programming, the sigma notation is something like (taking for example $\sum_{i = 0}^n f(i)$):

```
total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    total += f(i);
}
```

and the final value of the variable 'total' will be what the sum evaluates to.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Yiyuan! Very precise! Will mark as correct as soon as I'm allowed to.

Comment: No problem, very glad I could help!

Comment: Hahaha thanks for the code example! I did thought about it but didn't find a way to express it "math way" !

Answer (score 1):

$$0.4 \sum_{k=0}^5(0.2)^k$$
Q.E.D.